# log2 causes a fault in STM32F4 MCU in C

Tags: c, arm, stm32, stm32f4, stm32cubeide

Why does this code cause hard fault and jumps into infinite loop?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

void myfunc()
{  
    const double val = 1;
    double log_res = log2(val); // <----- THIS CAUSES A FAULT
    //double log_res = log2(1); // This works
}
```

When I replace `val` in the evil line by a hard-coded 1, the code works. So the problem happens only when I pass `val` to `log2` (as shown in code). Why is this happening?

I am using STM32CubeIDE (eclipse based), with STM32F429ZI MCU.

#### UPDATE:

Checking the exception in the disassembly window showed that this is the exception happened:

> fffffff9:   Failed to execute MI command:
>             -data-disassemble -s 4294967289 -e 4294967429 -- 3
>             Error message from debugger back end:
>             Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffe

Any one has idea why is this happening?

#### Update 2:

Debugging in the assembly instructions:

```
54            const double val = 1;
08000e0a:   mov.w   r3, #0
08000e0e:   ldr     r4, [pc, #64]   ; (0x8000e50 <myfunc+88>)
08000e10:   strd    r3, r4, [r7, #16]
55            double log_res = log2(val);
08000e14:   vldr    d0, [r7, #16] // <------ X THIS LINE CAUSES THE PROBLEM X
08000e18:   bl      0x8002a9c <log>
08000e1c:   vmov    r0, r1, d0
08000e20:   add     r3, pc, #36     ; (adr r3, 0x8000e48 <myfunc+80>)
08000e22:   ldrd    r2, r3, [r3]
08000e26:   bl      0x800085c <__divdf3>
```

The emphisized line has d0=0, r7=0x2002ffcc

After executing this line, the disassembler jumps to `WWDG_IRQHandler`.

#### Update 3:

GCC Assembler options (not sure what does this do):

```
-mcpu=cortex-m4 -g3 -c -x assembler-with-cpp --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb
```

GCC compiler options:

```
-mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DSTM32F429I_DISC1 -DSTM32 -DSTM32F429ZITx -DSTM32F4 -DDEBUG -DSTM32F429xx -c -I..\Inc -I../Inc/CMSIS/Include -I../Inc/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb
```

GCC linker options:

```
-mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"C:\Users\mne\STM32CubeIDE\workspace_1.0.0\MyUSB\STM32F429ZITX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="${ProjName}.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
```

#### Udpate 4:

The problem seems to happend with many functions of `math.h`, e.g. `fmin`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200119/discussion-on-question-by-mohammed-noureldin-log2-causes-a-hard-fault-in-stm32-m).

Comment: What's your MCU exactly? And what's your compiler option? It looks like you are using double precision instructions where the MCU does not support.

Comment: @BumsikKim I am using STM32F429ZI, I am not sure how I can exactly share my compiler options with you. I added the gcc command line options to the question, hopefully that is what you need.

Comment: If you used optimization, the compiler would probably fold the constant for you, and maybe even the `log2` call. `constexpr double first_set` or `static const` might also work. You’ll surely want it on for your production code.

Comment: I’m guessing this is a MCVE and the actual context is different, because why would you need to compute `log2(1)`, which is identically `0.0`, at runtime?

Comment: Is there a reason you have `-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb` as assembler and not compiler options?

Comment: Thank you @Davislor for your time. Actually I did not touch those settings, the IDE configured the compiler and assembler for me. I will try the answer you wrote when I come back to home.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I don’t know whether your IDE passes the assembler options to the compiler, in which case my guess is wrong and that won’t work. But those options look as if it’s compiling to assembly and then running an assembler. In that case, you should have those flags on both.

Comment: @Davislor I updated my compiler parameters in the question. Unfortunately the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

> 08000e14:   vldr    d0, [r7, #16] // <------ X THIS LINE CAUSES THE PROBLEM X

"d0" is a 64-bit VFP register. However, Cortex-M4F only has 32-bit FPU (registers s0, s1, etc.). Cortex-M7F has 64-bit FPU but that's not what you are using.

So the instruction is invalid for the Cortex-M4F core which causes the fault. I could duplicate this with GCC 2018-Q4 release. The problem will go away if you remove the `-mfloat-abi=hard`, as it then uses the ARM core CPU registers to pass the argument. So that's the fix I'd recommend.

As for the root cause, I will need to do some more investigations.

Comment: I updated my compiler parameters in the question. Unfortunately the problem still exists.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Hmmm. Does `-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=auto` work?

Comment: You removed -mfloat-abi=hard? You should not have to explicitly say -mfloat-abi=soft but go ahead and try that. If it still fails, double check the asm output again, it should not generate the "vldr d0,.." with soft FP ABI (unless your GCC is very broken). Also, what is the version of GCC you are using?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and for trying to reproduce the error! It works now! I figured out why this did not help before and helped now. I did a clean to the project and then rebuilt it with the new settings `-mfloat-abi=soft` and `no hardware FPU`. The clean was important to see the effect (I did not do clean before, and that is why this did not work).

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Not using the hardware FPU at all is something you should do only as an extreme last resort. What is the actual FPU? You should give the correct compiler flags to use that.

Comment: @Davislor, I did understand exactly what you mean. Isn't this what these parameters exactly do? `-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard`? I could not get the code to work without disabling the hardware. Do you suggest anything else?

Comment: @RichardatImageCraft have you found any fix where I should not disable my hardware FPU?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin You might be able to use `-mfloat-abi=softfp` for hardware FPU instructions but software FP linkage.

Comment: @Davislor could you please explain a bit more (maybe by editing your answer). Sorry I am still relatively new in dealing with this FPU problems.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be omitting the flags `-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb` from your compiler options, and including them only in your assembler options.  (You might substitute `-march=armv7-m -mtune=cortex-m4` for `-mcpu=cortex-m4`.)  Therefore, your compiler is generating code for the wrong floating-point ABI.  You specified the hard ABI, but are generating a call to the soft library function rather than inline assembly instructions.

**Edit:** If the compiler is generating instructions your FPU does not support, as Richard at ImageCraft observes, you might try changing the flags to `--mcpu=cortex-m4 --mfpu=auto`.

Note that any level of optimizaiton, even `-O1`, is enough for GCC to fold the constant and optimize the call to `double position = 0.0;`.  You might need to have the function `return position;` to get it to emit this code with optimizations on.  (I assume this is a simplified MCVE, as you would never actually need to compute `log2(1)` at runtime.)

Comment: I updated my compiler parameters in the question. Unfortunately the problem still exists.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Unfortunately, I don’t have a way to reproduce this problem. Defining multiple options that declare a target architecture looks suspicious to me, and I’d make sure you’re including and linking the correct libraries and only those.

Comment: The parameters are defined by the IDE actually, is there anything special I have to take care when linking `math.h`? again here I did nothing special, the IDE added the whole linker parameters (and I didn't change anything here).

Answer (score 0):

regarding your question:

*When I replace val in the evil line by a hard-coded 1, the code works. So the problem happens only when I pass val to log2 (as shown in code). Why is this happening?*

The following statement:

```
double position = log2(first_set);
```

is NOT passing the variable `val` to the function: `log2()`

I would expect such a coding error (since `first_set` is not defined) to result in the code not compiling.

Comment: I am sorry for confusing you. I edited some variable names to make the code easier and forgot to adapt the text. I fixed the code and question again.

Answer (score 0):

The STMF4 series does not support double precision floats. Change the double to float to use single precision floats.